# How to create buttons with Javascript that set a new view (extent and zoom)?

Tags: carto, java, carto-js

I am creating a web map using CartoDB, and am having trouble creating buttons that will set a new view when clicked. I am a novice when it comes to coding but i do have some basic knowledge.

I'm thinking its going to involve creating a new visualization using CartoDB's .createvis command and a SQL statement but I'm not sure.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/b9e589cd0942eaad5139) you have a working example with a "Reset Zoom" buttom. First you have to create a HTML kind of buttom:

```
<div id = 'reset'><p>Reset Zoom</p></div>
```

Second, you need to use JQuery in combination with the `setView` CartoDB.js function:

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
          map.setView([41.390205, 2.154007],12);
        });
```